# If you are setting a random combination for a 3 digit lock, then would it be a permutation or a combination?

Tags: permutations, terminology, combinations

I understand that permutations are used for specific positions and for orders, but for choosing or setting a combination, wouldn't it be a combination because it wants the number of possible combinations you can set?

Comment: This is a case where common English does not gibe with mathematical English.  A lock combination is a permutation.

Answer (score 0):

Permutations are for lists (order matters) and combinations are for groups (order doesn't matter).

Confusing as it is a combination lock, however in this case order matters so we need a permutation.

That is lock combo 123 is not the same as lock combo 321.